# Incompatible types when converting List to String array

Tags: java, arrays, list

I seem to be getting an error when trying to convert a list to an array, this is my code

`List text = loadFile(pathName);
 String[] convertedData = text.toArray(new String[text.size()]);`

The error I'm getting is:

incompatible types: java.lang.Object[] cannot be converted to java.lang.String[].

Not really sure why and if anymore information is needed ill be happy to post, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If loadFile(pathName) returns a list of String write List<String> text = loadFile(pathName);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a generic `List` of `String`s:

```
List<String> text = loadFile(pathName);
```

and make sure that the `loadFile` method returns a `List<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling the parameterless overload of `toArray()`, which returns `Object[]`. You can't assign an `Object[]` to an `String[]` variable.
To fix the problem do this:

```
 List<String> text = loadFile(pathName);
```